# How to fix the _ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, non-public symbols

Tags: ios, xcode, archive, testflight

I got apple mail following content:

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "App name". Please correct the following issues, then upload again. ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public symbols in "App name": _ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, _ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait. If method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further information, visit the Technical Support Information at http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

Get above error message app store when upload the app too app store, i removed the iAd.framework reference related all pods and library but still i got same error email.

Any have solution for this error, please share your thoughts..,

Thanks.

Comment: The final solution is to remove the Mobile App Tracker framework in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution is to remove the Mobile App Tracker framework in the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea might be to send a TSI because that is sounding like an apple problem.

Comment: Yesterday I have already sent TSI to Apple, but there is no clear solution yet.

Comment: The final solution is to remove the Mobile App Tracker framework in the project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to remove leftover iAd frameworks `libAdapterIAd` and `iAd.framework` from my build target. After that I did not get the error anymore when uploading a build.

[image]